# Booting into Ubuntu and then adding Ubuntu to Windows boot loader

Tags: ubuntu, grub, mbr, easybcd

I installed W7 Pro x64 and then I installed Ubuntu 10.04. During the Ubuntu install, I decided NOT to allow GRUB 2 to be the boot loader for both Ubuntu and Windows. I followed the advice of a tutorial and decided to select the "Advanced" button at the very end of the Ubuntu install to install the GRUB 2 boot loader onto my very first Ubuntu partition (sda5 IIRC).

Now when I boot my computer, I don't get any boot screen whatsoever. It simply boots right into Windows 7. If you didn't know better, you wouldn't be able to tell I have Ubuntu installed.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.rightnowintech.com/2010/08/use-windows-bootloader-to-boot-windows.html) but no changes occurred. I still cannot access Ubuntu.

So, my question is this, since I cannot access Ubuntu at the boot screen, how do I configure the Windows boot loader to allow me to boot into either W7 or Ubuntu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) to modify the Windows 7 Bootloader to add Ubuntu, it's very easy and straightforward. I have used it on many machines.

Comment: Strangest thing. I swear I did that before and nothing. I tried it again and it worked. Now i just have to decrease the GRUB time to "0" so it doesn't boot into GRUB when I select Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I would actually keep 5 seconds on GRUB, as it can come in useful if you have made a kernel update and can't boot into the latest one. At least you can boot into an older kernel.

Answer (score 0):

`sda5` is a logical partition.  Since the BIOS reads the MBR at the beginning of a drive, it will not read the bootloader at `sda5`.  Boot from the Ubuntu CD and reinstall the bootloader onto the disk device `sda` itself.  Make sure that GRUB is set to allow booting from either Windows 7 or Ubuntu.